# Custom post type doen't have code block in the tools

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm currently learning WP and I made a custom post type, but it doesn't have Gutenberg enabled. For example I can't add a block with code.

How can I enable the Gutenberg editor on my custom post type?

@edit

```
$restaurants_args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Restauracje',
        'singular_name' => 'Restauracje',
        'all_items' => 'Wszystkie restauracje',
        'add_new' => 'Dodaj nową restaurację',
        'add_new_item' => 'Dodaj nową restaurację',
        'edit_item' => 'Edytuj restaurację',
        'new_item' => 'Nowa restauracja',
        'view_item' => 'Wyświetl restaurację',
        'search_item' => 'Szukaj w restauracjach',
        'not_found' => 'Nie znaleziono w restauracjach',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'Brak restauracji w koszu',
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'public_queryable' => true,
    'guttenberg' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats'
    ),
    'has_archive' => true
    );
```

Comment: Add `'show_in_rest' => true,` to your custom post type registration arguments.

Comment: OK, it works but I lost other options like - custom field posts and my own taxonomy. Is it possible to have all thinks?

Comment: Post your code. It's easier to help if we can see that. Edit your question to include that. My guess is something didn't get closed properly.

Comment: There is something else missing. Can you post where you register the post type and your taxonomy? What you have there, wouldn't break anything else. Remove this `'guttenberg' => true,`. That's not a valid argument.

Comment: Yes, I registered, becouse I can see that in old editor. Or maybe I don't know where it is.